# What does "murder tax-wise" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Apple, Google, Facebook and Amazon stock all ended the day in the red with Amazon down 2%. Trump has specifically claimed that "Amazon is getting away with **murder tax-wise**," and could try to take action to change that.

source:http://money.cnn.com/2016/11/09/technology/Trump-Silicon-valley/index.html

Comment: [The suffix "-wise" means something like "in reference to" or "related to" or "in the manner of".](http://www.onestopenglish.com/community/your-english/word-grammar/your-english-word-grammar-wise/550157.article)  So they're "getting away with murder" *in relation to taxes*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't divide like that. The idiom is "getting away with murder", which isn't literally about murder, but about  'getting away with' (= not being caught or punished for) things.

So he means that they're doing something wrong about their taxes, and not being called, or caught, or punished, for it.